# dynamic buttons in access 2007

Tags: ms-access, dynamic, ms-access-2007

I have been pulled onto a project at work that deals with rebuilding our machine lockout database. The current database was built in Microsoft Access (2003 I believe), and it's a bit of a cluster... One of the biggest issues that I see with the current database, is that it is very difficult to navigate.

One idea that I had to remedy this issue was to setup a form that was populated by dynamic buttons. These buttons would then allow users to navigate through the various tables. However, my lack of knowledge with Access 2007 is a bit of a hindrance, and I am not sure how to go about doing such a thing (or if its even possible). Through my searching, I came across a couple different articles that indicated that dynamic controls are not possible in Access due to limitations in indexing (something along those lines), but I am not sure if this would apply to dynamic button creation.

Any links to examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by dynamic buttons? What will the button do when the user clicks on it? Will it open the table?

Answer (score 2):

Put the buttons on the forms, and then control what they see at a given time by setting ButtonName.Visible = True or False.  People try to get too cute, that's really the simplest solution.